# Windows Share permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a SQL/File server that I am replicating a File Share and SQL instance, using ArcServer RHA, to a Replica server.  Everything seems to work as far as the replication of the SLQ instance and Share is concerned.  When I fail over to the Replica server the DNS Host A record is modified to point to the Replica Server IP Address so if I do an NSLOOKUP on ServerA it then points to the IP Address of ServerB.  Ans since the SQL instance is named the same I can still map my ODBC connections to ServerA and I can still make a SQL connection.  When I try to do a \ServerA\Share I get an error that says I do not have permissions to the Share. I think this is because it uses keberose authentication and the Share is tied to the actual sever host name.  I have tried puting in a CNAME and pointing it to ServerA and Disabling Strict Name Checking on ServerB as well as adding the CNAME to the OptionalNames in the registry but I am still getting the error when I have the ServerA powered off.  Is there a way to reset the Authentication of the Share to use the DNS Cname?

Comment: Is it just the share you are having issues with? Perhaps using a DFS namespace would help you, since you can use one path to access multiple replicated shares. As it's just a referral to the underlying share, there's no need to mess about with DNS.

Comment: If this is what the ArcServer RHA product is supposed to do, then I bet this is addressed in the product documentation somewhere. Have you look at that yet?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need to enable disablestrictnamechecking in the registry of ServerB? - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660057(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable strict name checking on server B like joeqwerty said in his comment.